# Is it possible to add CDN on HTML via a PHP include?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, cdn

I'm creating a website for homework and it's going to have multiple pages. I'm using bootstrap 4 and for each page, I have to declare a lot of links and scripts on the head of the HTML.

My question is if it's possible to add a single link via HTML or a PHP include so I can use a single line for all the additions and edit them all on a single file.

**This is what I have**

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**I want something like this**

```
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alltheotherlinksandscripts.php">
</head>
```

**Or this**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php
        include_once "alllinks.php";
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body> </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can. Put the header in a separate php file and you can include it in all files.

```
<head>
 <?php include('header.php'); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using script tags? Due to we are calling to JS libraries, the correct way might be to use something as follows: 
`<script src="all-libraries.js"></script>`. Is possible? Or maybe is too complex in coding and is better and simpler to use php include?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set all links (js/css libraries) in one file i.e `alllinks.php`

and call that file in your `<head>` part like..

```
<head>
    <?php include('alllinks.php'); ?>
</head>
```